# Why RequestBody in HttpServletRequest is an InputStream?

Tags: java, http, servlets, web, operating-system

I know that in BIO, web container receives the request and wrap it in a HttpServletRequest object, and We can get Header and other stuff from it. 
I think the HTTP Message has been copied to User-space. But why the request body is still an inputstream ? Can anybody explain that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

`HttpServletRequest` is an interface from the servlet specification. There are many servlet container implementations including jetty, tomcat and websphere to name a few. Each has its own implementation of `HttpServletRequest`.

Using an InputStream gives freedom to the servlet implementation to source the request body value from wherever it likes. One implementation might use a local file and `FileInputStream`, another may have a byte array in memory and use `ByteArrayInputStream`, another might source from a cache or database etc.

Another benefit of `InputStream` over a byte array is that you can stream over it only holding a small chunk in memory at a time. There's no requirement to have a large byte array (eg gigabytes) in memory all at once.

Imagine a video sharing site where each user can upload 1GB videos. If the servlet spec were to impose byte array instead of `InputStream` then a server with 8GB of ram could only support 8 concurrent uploads. With `InputStream` you can have a small buffer of ram for each upload so could support hundreds/thousands of concurrent 1GB uploads

Comment: I think there is another question, What is a stream? In my mind, a stream is a abstract for data from socket or file to memory(user-space)。 And now I think the RequestBody has been copied to user space,  can I think there are something else in Java can be regarded as inputstream if we can handle it as a stream。

Comment: If this is right, I have another question yet. RequestBody(as a stream) can only be read once. If I want to read it many times, I must put it in a byte array or a buffer. So the question is What is the cost  if I read the inputstream and write to the output stream(such as a socket). The cost is compare to I send the request body to the other server directly(in fact, this is the route senerio such as  spring cloud Zuul)